# Prototype function creating elements and using inheritance invoked on load instead of on click

Tags: javascript, oop

I apologize if the following are stupid questions, this is my first time trying something with OO JS which goes beyond the very basic tutorials out there.
If I get to understand the following questions, it would constitute something like a person breakthrough:-)

Basically, I want to create an element- a div with a background pic- on click and append it to the button.(Later on i want to create an additional button which will replace the above pic with another one).
The pictures are stored in an Array.

If i run this with the commented out lines 37-57, it all works, but i do not want to write that function every time to create the next element.

So I have created the function object "Nation"(lines 4 to 30) and want to pass 2 arguments on call, "land"(name of nation) and "imageIndex"(index of picture in the array).

Here is where the problems start. I want to call new Nation on click(line, but it is executed straight on page load instead. How to fix that?

And I have not passed the second argument now, as I could not figure out how to do it, so I just used line 13 to set the BG pic. But the goal would be to set the BG pic by passing a second argument to the function.

```
var croats = new Nation("croatia");
document.getElementById("newDom")
.addEventListener("click", croats.create("croatia"));
```

That is the event handling and the code is here:

http://codepen.io/damianocel/pen/gPggLB

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should simply pass a **function** as 2nd argument of the `addEventListener`:

```js
document.getElementById("newDom").addEventListener("click", function () {
  croats.create("croatia")
});
```

See for example: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener#Example

As your code is currently set, it executes `croats.create()` when attaching the listener, instead of storing a reference to a function (called "*listener*" or "*callback*") to be executed when the event occurs.

Updated CodePen: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KVqgdP

Comment: Thank you very much, this helps a great deal.
But how can i create another instance of nation which inherits everything but the setting the css for the background?
I would like to pass an argument for the position of the pic in the array.

Comment: Something like {new Nation.create(nation,indexOfPic in aray)}.
Thank you again.

Comment: That would probably need to slightly modify your `Nation` class, but nothing really difficult. You should make it a new question and include your code for `Nation`.

Comment: That is some amazing solution there from you, thanks so much.
I have modified the class myself, I can now pass an indexof array as argument to pick which image goes into the target.
Lol, the thing with the missing callback should have been....obvious, very smart solution with the createFunctionClickListener function, i was actually just about to ask how to do exactly that:-)
I will now extend the page and add click through galleries to each nation, and post a new question if I need help.
Thanks again, you have helped me with 2 replies so much, sometimes stuff like this took me weeks.

Comment: One more thing, if i add the creation of two more button into the nation class, (previous and next button), I know in jquery i would need to use the .on method like $(document).on("click", "newElement" , function(){ etc }) on dynamicaly created elements. Is this the same in vanilla JS? Or can I just add an eventListener after creation of the node?

Comment: Yes you can use `addEventListener` on an Element just after having created it.